# Technical term for "flat" tree structure

Tags: sql, tree

I have a table with a tree structure.

```
id  parent name 
---------------
1   NULL   A   
2   1      B   
3   2      C
4   2      D   
5   NULL   E
6   5      F
7   5      G
```

My SP returns a "flat" record set based on the nodes level (which I later export to excel)

```
level1 level2 level3 id name path
---------------------------------
A                    1  A    A
       B             2  B    A->B
              C      3  C    A->B->C
              D      4  D    A->B->D
E                    5  E    E
       F             6  F    E->F
       G             7  G    E->G
```

What could be the technical term for such structure? (Is it a pivot?)

<sup><sup>P.S: Mostly, I need to know  the technical term for naming this SP, and what to display to the end user in the UI.</sup></sup>

Comment: You might want to include other data, which could leave your flat result set not really looking like a pivot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Exactly , there is some other data, like the node Path and other columns. and this is exactly my dilemma. it's not really a "pivot". but the pivot is the level.

Comment: You should show a better example which demonstrates what a full tree might look like.  Then figure out how to name/describe it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I made an edit. so if there are other columns it is no longer a pivot?

Comment: This edit doesn't change anything.  What I had in mind is a height 2 full binary tree, i.e. `B` has two children, `C` has two children, etc.  I'm not sure what you end up with would even have a name.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks. is it more clear now?

Comment: I'd go with "flattened hierarchy". The content of the `path` column is usually called "materialized path"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I think you are right (please post as an answer). I also found this article which is somehow similar to what I did: [Flattening a parent-child hierarchy](https://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/flattening-or-naturalizing-a-parent-child-hierarchy/)

Comment: It's also known as a directed acyclic graph.